# How can I embed a license in a PDF file with PDFBox?

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am generating PDF exports in my software product and would like to use (and embed) Abobe's free Source Sans Pro font. According to [the license](https://fonts.adobe.com/variations/17265/eula) I must distribute a copyright notice and the license text with each copy of the font. It says:

> "These can be included either as stand-alone text files,
> human-readable headers or in the appropriate machine-readable metadata
> fields within text or binary files as long as those fields can be
> easily viewed by the user."

Since I'm planning to embed the font in the PDF export files, I'm looking for a practical way to include the license and the copyright notice in them.

- Are there PDF header fields available for this purpose?
- What could an "appropriate machine-readable metadata field" look like in a PDF file?
- How can I include such headers in Java using PDFBox?

Comment: Why not attach them as PDF attachment? See `EmbeddedFiles.java` in the examples subproject in the source code download.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites:

(1) Put it in the font itself. It depends what kind of font format you are using however most of them have meta data. The license should be visible there. You can find some infos about this topic [here](http://silnrsi.github.io/FDBP/en-US/Copyright_and_Licensing.html). Your font has this already correctly set:

[image: screenshot of font properties]

(2) If you want to additionally put it somewhere in the PDF - the PDF XMP Meta data could be a good place imho. You could add your own values (license) or use an existing field like copyright notice...

[image: screenshot of pdf xmp metadata]